# Oracle alter, update and system crash before commit

Tags: sql, oracle, transactions, commit

In an oracle sql statement, I issued three update commands and then an ALTER command to add a column. System crashes before I COMMIT the query. Will update and alter statements be written to the db? My assumption is only alter statement will be written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Oracle Database implicitly commits the current transaction before and after every DDL statement.

[More](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_1001.htm#i2099120)

If `ALTER` statement executed successfully before the crash then the previous uncommitted `DML`s will be committed.